# Syntax highlighting stopped working

Tags: vimrc

I was just started with Vim. While experimenting with basic customization techniques, it began to behave differently.

**Somehow the default configurations changed to very basic for both GVim and terminal version.**

- No syntax highlighting.
- Links are shown in bars ( |example| ).
- No mouse support (for terminal version only).

**Currently both `.vimrc` and `.gvimrc` files are empty and it was the same when it worked without issues.** I think I can change them by editing them. But I wonder how did this happen.

I am using Gnome on debian 4.19. I tried reinstalling both Vim and GVim. It didn't work.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: the files and environment variables vim reads at startup are documented in [`:h startup`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#startup) - i suggest double-checking that those mentioned in steps 1 and 3 are in their default state

Comment: btw, links in vimdoc files _are_ written with bars around them but syntax highlighting conceals the bars :) for mouse support in the terminal you may need to `:set mouse=a`. also, please check that your version of vim was compiled with the necessary features - `:ve` should list `+syntax` and `+mouse` in its output. debian has several vim packages compiled with different flags.

Comment: @ngn Thank you very much for the response. But I had them working before without any issue. It changed all of a sudden. How did it happened that's what I am trying to find.

Comment: "Empty `.vimrc`" is not the same as "no `.vimrc`". Delete it, and you'll get your syntax and mouse back (hint: this is in `defaults.vim`).

Comment: @Matt Yes! It worked. Can't believe it was that simple. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Very, *very* [related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58694994/4400820)

Comment: Thanks @D.BenKnoble. I wish if I had seen it before posting this . (I did search many times. It didn't shown up)

Comment: @Anees np! Glad you got the answers you were looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Empty `.vimrc` is not the same as no `.vimrc`. Once I deleted it, it worked fine as before.

Thanks to [@Matt](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/22797/matt)

Comment: Usually one **wants** to have own .vimrc, so it often makes sense to include those "advanced" defaults manually by adding the line `runtime defaults.vim` on top of .vimrc, and then twiddling them a bit. Deleting the whole .vimrc certainly also works, but is a bit of a radical measure.